# which session type is better for a asp.net internet application

Tags: asp.net, session

I am trying to get the pros and cons of the session management techniques i.e. State server, Sql, Inproc

My application is hosted on internet. Any knowledge of which one would be best for which case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **production servers**, you should never use **InProc** to store **user sessions**, please exclude it from your considerations.

InProc sessions expire when your IIS server stops,restarts or crashes.

Whether to use **StateServer** or **SQL** depends on your needs. As **a general rule of thumb**,
If you have access to an **ASP.NET StateServer**, it is better to store them on your **StateServer**, separating those user session data from your **back-end database**, as session data shouldn't be permanently stored.

There are other concerns such as what sort data are stored in your session, serialisation of session data etc, that may affect your decision.

If you could describe more about your application's desire behaviour, we could provide better suggestions.